# No Provider for router in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-providers

As a newbie, I am having issues setting up routes in Angular 2. 
Though I am pretty sure, it is something very basic I am missing.

All I want is my `App Component` to load up and show me the title. And just below it, a link that would load up the `contact-list component` in the router-outlet section.

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from './contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <a routerLink="/contact-list">Contact List</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'Welcome to my Dream App!';
}
```

Here is the `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactCardComponent } from './contact-card.component';
import { ContactsListComponent } from './contacts-list.component';

RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path:'',
    redirectTo:'app',
    pathMatch:'full',
  },
  {
    path:'app',
    component:AppComponent
  },
  {
    path:'contact-list',
    component:ContactsListComponent
  },
  {
    path:'contact-details/:id',
    component:ContactCardComponent
  }
]);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactsListComponent,
    ContactCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But is says:

`error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:2:4 caused by: No provider for Router!`

No Provider for Router.

What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

If I do :

```
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <contacts-list></contacts-list>
    `
```

in `app.component.ts`, it works fine.

After the solution posted, I see repeated lines:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import RouterModule into your module definition and "imports" array:

```
const ROUTES = [
  // HERE ROUTES DEFINITIONS
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: []
})
export default class YourModuleDefinition{

}
```

So your code should look like that:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactCardComponent } from './contact-card.component';
import { ContactsListComponent } from './contacts-list.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     ContactsListComponent,
     ContactCardComponent
   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot([
       {
          path:'',
          redirectTo:'app',
          pathMatch:'full',
       },
       {
          path:'app',
          component:AppComponent
       },
       {
          path:'contact-list',
          component:ContactsListComponent
       },
       {
          path:'contact-details/:id',
          component:ContactCardComponent
        }
     ]);
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

The forRoot static class method of the RouterModule with the provided configuration and added to the imports array provides the routing concerns for the module.

More info here: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

Comment: In my approach also I have imported RouterModule in my module definition. So What's the problem?

Comment: It works but it shows me repeated things. Please see the update.

Comment: Oh Got it. Thanks